# how to set background-color when div is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color

I slide down and display a hidden div on click.

```
<style>
    hide { display: hidden;}
    content {  background-color: black; }
</style>

<div class="content, hide">

<script>
    $(.content).slideDown();<br>
    $(.content).removeClass("hidden");
</script>
```

everything works except setting the background color.  I have tried setting the background color with jQuery `.css()` but it doesn't work.  When I remove the `hide` class it works.

Comment: remove the comma in the class name?

Comment: class="content hide"
And
$(.content).removeClass("hide");

Comment: and what ist that <br> doing in the `<script>` section? remove it!

Comment: add `'`  $('.content').slideDown();

Comment: There are couple of mistakes in your posted code snippet. Also note that CSS class selectors must start with a leading period `.foo`. There are no `hide` or `content` elements to get styled unless you create them via JavaScript.

Comment: there is no value 'hidden' for display property, `display` may be `none`

Answer (score 1):

So a few points:

1. Remove comma from class names `<div class="content hide">...</div>`
2. CSS classes should start with a full stop/period (.)

   `.hide { display: hidden; }`
   `.content {  background-color: black; }`
3. `display: hidden` is in correct, you are after `display:none` in your hide class. Alternatively you are looking for `visibility:hidden`.
4. jQuery selector should contain quotes `$('.content')`
5. The class you are removing should be hide not hidden `$('.content').removeClass("hide");`
6. Technically you do not need to remove the `.hide` class as `slideDown()` will add a `display:block` override.
7. In your script you seem to have a random `<br>` which will cause a syntax error.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.content').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.content {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
}
.content h1 { color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content hide">
  <h1>My Content</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArturTomczyk awesome, just hit the tick to mark this as correct and help others in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `comma` from `class` property of div

```
<div class="content, hide" to <div class="content hide"
```

Make css like this:

```
.hide { display: hidden; }
.content {  background-color: black; }
```

Make jquery like this:

```
$('.content').slideDown();
$('.content').removeClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code: "remove , from the html class, and add . to the classes in css, and add '' to the jquery"

**HTML**

```
<div class="content hide">
```

**CSS**

```
.hide { display: hidden; }
.content { background-color: black; }
```

**Script**

```
$('.content').slideDown();
$('.content').removeClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check with the below code

```
<style>
.hide { display: none; }
.content {  background-color: black; }
</style>
<div class="content hide">
<p>sdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="clickme">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


$("#clickme").click(function() {
$(".content").slideDown();
$(".content").removeClass("hide");

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="scroll_Div" class="content hide">

.hide { display: hidden; }
.content {  background-color: black; }

<script>
    $(document).click(function(){
      $("#scroll_Div").removeClass("hidden");
    });
```